# Decoding a quote about lying

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

I'm trying to understand the sentence construction and the meaning of this quote by Otto Von Bismarck. Can someone please help?

> People never lie so much as before an election, during a war, or after a hunt.

Comment: This doesn't seem too complex to me - what part are you having trouble with? I presume that it is actually a translation from his native German, since it reads absolutely fine in English.

Answer (score 3):

It means that people lie most in the following cases:

1) **Before elections**
(They make fake promises, give false hope to people in order to get their votes, and forget/ignore those promises once they are in power)

2) **During war**
(Leaders and authorities lie in war for multiple purposes, either give false information to people to avoid panic, or ignite them by accusing the other party wrongly etc)

3) **After a hunt**
(Hunters might boast about their hunt falsely etc)

Comment: Worth noting that the quote, it seems, is intended to be somewhat humorous and relatable.